# global varibles appear as null in dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to do the simple task of copying the value of the first textbox to the second textbox.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">   
         <script src="1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        textbox1: <input id="textbox1" onkeyup="TextCopy()" type="text"> <br>
        textbox2: <input id="textbox2"  type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is my js file:**

```
const text1 = document.getElementById("textbox1");
const text2 = document.getElementById("textbox2");

function TextCopy() {

    text2.value = text1.value;
}
```

**The error I get is:**

```
1.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at TextCopy (1.js:6:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (1.html:7:73)
```

If I declare `text1` and `text2` inside the function, then I get no errors and it works correctly. So why doesn't it work when I declare them as global variables?

Comment: Just to be clear put your `<script src="1.js"></script>` at the end of the  `<body>` just before the closing tag

Answer (score 0):

Your elements don't exist at the time your script is run. That is why people put their script files at the end of the body, and not in the head. You can also use the `defer` attribute.
`<script src="script.js" defer></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You fetch your elements faster than HTML has them rendered, that's why JS can't find them in DOM. Move script to the end of `body` or wrap it in DOM Ready event:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">   
    </head>
    <body>
        textbox1: <input id="textbox1" onkeyup="TextCopy()" type="text"> <br>
        textbox2: <input id="textbox2"  type="text">

         <script src="1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const text1 = document.getElementById("textbox1");
    const text2 = document.getElementById("textbox2");
    
    function TextCopy() {
        text2.value = text1.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your answer really better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/16540390? I would assume a user with rep >41k to know how to vote to close as duplicate and not to add another duplicate answer. That's a very common and frequent question.

Answer (score 0):

Your sript executes before the page has the time to fully load, in order to force javascript to wait for the DOM to be loaded completely you must use the **defer** keyword in your script tag

```
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">   
     <script src="1.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    textbox1: <input id="textbox1" onkeyup="TextCopy()" type="text"> <br>
    textbox2: <input id="textbox2"  type="text">
</body>
```

Comment: _"you must"_ is wrong in your answer. There are multiple different solutions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/16540390

Comment: I never stated that there was only one solution. @jabaa

Comment: You wrote _"you must use the defer keyword in your script tag"_. That means, there is no other way.